# How to get Google Play Store Subscriptions History

Tags: google-play-services

Is there any other way to get user subscriptions history (Detailed transactions) ?
Any help would be **greatly appreciated**

no API that returns detailed transactions of all subscription.

Comment: Just record the events from pub/sub, in order to write history.